# (re)Connecting a device fails with a subscription exception

Tags: java, azure

I'm using the azure iot device SDK (1.3.31) to connect simulated devices. **For some devices** I'm getting this exception when making this call:

```
//pseudo code    
deviceInfo.device = registryManager.getDevice(deviceId);
String deviceConnectionString = new StringBuilder()
                .append("HostName=").append(hubHostname)
                .append(";DeviceId=").append(device.getDeviceId())
                .append(";SharedAccessKey=").append(device.getPrimaryKey())
                .toString();

DeviceClient deviceClient = new DeviceClient(deviceConnectionString, IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT);

deviceClient.open();
```

And the exception that bubbles up:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to subscribe to topic :devices/sim3_0001/messages/devicebound/# because java.io.EOFExceptionConnection lost
    at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.MqttIotHubConnection.open(MqttIotHubConnection.java:142) ~[iot-device-client-1.2.30.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.transport.mqtt.MqttTransport.open(MqttTransport.java:83) ~[iot-device-client-1.2.30.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceIO.open(DeviceIO.java:212) ~[iot-device-client-1.2.30.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceClient.open(DeviceClient.java:188) ~[iot-device-client-1.2.30.jar:na]
```

I did a little digging into the library code and found that my connection is getting dropped before the subscribe gets a response; this is the exception that is consumed and turned into an IOException:

```
Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:146)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Lost connection to the server. Reconnecting 0 time.
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:107)
```

Additionally, I hooked up the iothub-explorer to see if I got any extra useful information. This is what it spit out on my open call:

```
    body: 
  protocol:      Mqtt
  authType:      { "scope": "device", "type": "sas", "issuer": "iothub" }
  time:          2017-06-13T21:13:48.2406702Z
  operationName: deviceConnect
  category:      Connections
  level:         Information
  deviceId:      sim3_0001
  ipAddress:     xx.xx.xxx.XXX
enqueuedTimeUtc:       Tue Jun 13 2017 17:13:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)
offset:                355136
applicationProperties: 
  category:      Connections
  level:         Information
  operationName: deviceConnect
sequenceNumber:        705
annotations: 
  x-opt-sequence-number: 705
  x-opt-offset:          355136
  x-opt-enqueued-time:   Tue Jun 13 2017 17:13:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)
offset:                355536
enqueuedTimeUtc:       Tue Jun 13 2017 17:13:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)
body: 
  protocol:          Mqtt
  authType:          { "scope": "device", "type": "sas", "issuer": "iothub" }
  time:              2017-06-13T21:13:48.3656729Z
  operationName:     deviceDisconnect
  category:          Connections
  level:             Error
  statusCode:        404
  statusType:        404104
  statusDescription: DeviceConnectionClosedRemotely
  deviceId:          sim3_0001
  ipAddress:         xx.xx.xxx.XXX
annotations: 
  x-opt-sequence-number: 706
  x-opt-offset:          355536
  x-opt-enqueued-time:   Tue Jun 13 2017 17:13:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)
applicationProperties: 
  category:      Connections
  level:         Error
  operationName: deviceDisconnect
sequenceNumber:        706
```

Another note: new devices connect/subscribe successfully, it seems like they fail more regularly on reconnect. If I put the open call in a loop and retry after a 1 second sleep the devices eventually connect successfully.

Comment: Interestingly, if I change the protocol to IotHubClientProtocol.AMQPS everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer to this that the azure iot hub device library for the MQTT protocol only allows one connection per application. The library only creates one MQTT connection, so if you create a 2nd device and try to connect one of them will be forcibly disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information `java.io.IOException: Unable to subscribe to topic :devices/sim3_0001/messages/devicebound/# because java.io.EOFExceptionConnection lost`, I think you were trying to receive cloud-to-device messages via to subscribe using `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#` as a Topic Filter. The subsection `Migrating a device app from AMQP to MQTT` & `Receiving cloud-to-device messages` of the Azure offical document [`Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#) had explained the reason of your issue as below.

> **Receiving cloud-to-device messages**
>
> To receive messages from IoT Hub, a device should subscribe using `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#` as a **Topic Filter**. The multi-level wildcard ***#*** in the Topic Filter is used only to allow the device to receive additional properties in the topic name. IoT Hub does not allow the usage of the ***#*** or ***?*** wildcards for filtering of sub-topics. Since IoT Hub is not a general purpose pub-sub messaging broker, it only supports the documented topic names and topic filters.

For Azure IoT Hub, "MQTT doesn't support abandon/reject, so we will only display the messaged received from IoTHub and return COMPLETE". There is an offical [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/device/iot-device-samples/send-receive-sample/src/main/java/samples/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/SendReceive.java#L94-L113) on GitHub, which you can refer to to change your code and make it works with MQTT.

Comment: I am not explicitly subscribing to anything, I'm just calling the DeviceClient.open method which subscribes to that topic in the azure device library. Interestingly, it works occasionally; if I spin up 10 connections with 10 different devices 5 or 6 of the open calls will succeed.

Comment: If you look in device/transport/mqtt/MqttMessaging.java you'll see that once the connection is made it subscribes immediately to that topic:

this.subscribeTopic = "devices/" + deviceId + "/messages/devicebound/#";

Comment: Can you provide another look at this one? It's still an issue for us!